# Pentaho DI / Kettle / Spoon Configuration with External Jars

Tags: xslt, pentaho, classnotfoundexception, kettle, spoon

I am deveoloping a custom plugin for Pentaho DI / Kettle 4.4 and use custom Validation and XSLT jars as part of it.

Those jars are referenced in plugin.xml along with the plugin's jar itself and deployed in the same location as the plugin's jar.

When I try to load this plugin in Spoon GUI, I can see and run the plugin fine till I reach the reference to the external jars and after that I get ClassNotFOund Exception.

I have tried following so far but has not worked :

1. Add the expernal Jars to libext folder and expect those to be picked up automatically. - Failed. Jars not loaded.
2. Add -cp command line option to Spoon.bat and specify the Jar files -  Did not work.
3. Turned on -verbose option and search everywhere in the output but the Jars are ignored.
4. Deployed the Jars next to the plugin's Jar file in the plugin's folder.  - Jars are not recognized.
5. From Within the plugin, if I dynamically load (using Reflection and URL Class Loader) I am able to force the loading of the Jars and it works that way but I would like a simpler classpath fix.
6. Any class that I reference in the Jar through XSL externsion (XALAN-J Java Extension) is still not recognized / loaded and XSL terminates at the beginning of Extension call.
7. Searched Google and this site for something similar but did not find specific answers on why SPoon behaves so differently and avoids external code and content.
8. A similar issue is reported here though its too old and has not shown final conclusive fix. I tried all that it said. http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-77190.html

Requesting someone to help me identify whats missing. Thanks in advance,

Comment: BTW This is JDK 1.7 behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this seemingly obscure website and it fixed all pain.

http://www.arulraj.net/2014/09/how-to-access-external-java-libraries-with-in-pentaho.html

Basically, go to the launcher folder and edit the launcher.properties file to include any path, library etc. and it fixes all the issues I reported above. Wish Kettle documentatation had answers like this.